# composite id mapping configuration

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I need configure the Set.hbm.xml file for mapping this table:

TABLE "Set" [PK: IdSet int
             PK: dProject int
                 Unit char
                 NumDisc int]

TABLE "Project" [PK: IdProject int
                     Name varchar
                     DateBegin datetime
                     DateEnd    datetime]

I have this configuration, the problem is that don't work, mappinn error...

THIS IS THE SET.hbm.xml

```
<composite-id>
  <key-property name="IdSet" column="IdSet"  class="Set"></key-property>
  <key-many-to-one class="Project" name="IdProject" column="IdProject"  ></key-many-to-one>
</composite-id>

<property name="IdSetState" />
<property name="IdPriority" />
<property name="Unit" />
<property name="NumDisc" />
<property name="NumSet" />
```

THIS IS THE Set entity class:

```
   public class Set
    {
        public virtual int IdSet { get; set; }
        public virtual int IdProject { get; set; }
        public virtual int IdSetState { get; set; }
        public virtual int IdPriority { get; set; }
        public virtual char Unit { get; set; }
        public virtual int NumDisc { get; set; }
        public virtual int NumSet { get; set; }
}
```

How can configure this??

Comment: Can you post your mapping file?

Comment: "the composite-id have a definition for key not recognized..."

Comment: It's hard to understand only with "has not been declared a class attribute"... have you the complete stack or the InnerException?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is "Key" and not "key-property"?

```
<composite-id>
     <key-property name="IdSet" column="IdSet" lazy="proxy" class="Set"></key>
     <key-many-to-one name="IdProject" column="IdProject" lazy="proxy"
 class="Project"></key-many-to-one>
</composite-id>
```

[NHibernate and Composite Keys](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2010/06/30/nhibernate-and-composite-keys.aspx)

Comment: <composite-id name="id" class="Set">
      <key-property name="IdSet" column="IdSet"  class="Set"></key-property>
      <key-many-to-one class="Project" name="IdProject" column="IdProject"  ></key-many-to-one>
    </composite-id>          ----->Now, MappingException: "has not been declared a class attribute"

Comment: If I helped you with the main error you can at least upvote! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you have to specify `class="Set"`? Id is of type int , you could remove it

```
<composite-id>
  <key-property name="IdSet" column="IdSet"></key-property>
</composite-id>
```

also `int IdProject` should be `Project Project`?